# WebGL Error : ArrayBuffer not big enough for request in case of gl.LUMINANCE

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to render a image using a Uint8Array and getting **WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: texImage2D: ArrayBufferView not big enough for request**.

```
var gl = currentImage.gl;
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, columns, rows, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, Buffer);
```

On few images, it works fine, but it throws ArrayBuffer not big enough for request error for few images.

But if I subtract 1 from columns and rows , it works fine but image gets tilted.
I can however maintain a 2d canvas and push it to GPU but I don't want to maintain it as it kills some performance and I need to take care of a canvas unnecessarily.

This is what works after subtracting from 1.

```
var gl = currentImage.gl;
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, columns-1, rows-1, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, Buffer);
```

Am I doing anything wrong or missing anything?

Comment: What are the precise cases where it goes wrong? E.g. parameter values, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem textures have a width that doesn't divide by 4, and you're not accounting for UNPACK_ALIGNMENT.

Try

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the textures that fail?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with code that looks just like this. Don't have this issue with textures that are 1920x1080, 1280x720, and 640x360, but 854x480 is a problem.

Comment: worked like a charm, I don't have to maintain Canvas or RGBA data now, thanks a ton